# Is there wubi.exe that can support ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64?

Tags: 12.04, installation, wubi

I have downloaded Ubuntu 12.04.2 64 bit, and I tried to install it with WUBI. I put the ubuntu ISO and WUBI in the same folder. When I installed it with WUBI, it starts downloading ubuntu-12.04.2-wubi-amd64.tar.xz, which took nearly 2 hours because my internet connection is slow.

I didn't face this problem with previous versions of Ubuntu.

How can I avoid this issue? Is there a version of WUBI that can support ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso with previous version of Ubuntu?

---

Screenshot of the issue:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I'm not getting your issue. Is it because it's so slow to download?

Comment: I mean, in previous version no need to download like that. There is no waiting process like that.

Total time for the whole installation is around 30 mins only.

Comment: Previous versions as in less than 12.04? or as in 12.04.1/12.04? Could you also retry downloading the previous versions to see if you have the same issue with them too? Also note that ubuntu 12.04 is 50MB bigger than 11.10 and older

Comment: Just now I uninstall 12.10 version. When I installed 12.10, i downloaded 12.1 iso and extracted all. Then i run wubi.exe and follow the instruction. Total time to finish the installation is around 30 mins only.

Comment: I wounder why do I need to download extra. It should be in the ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's available here: http://people.canonical.com/~evand/wubi/precise/wubi-r273-signed.exe

It's been fixed for the bug you are experiencing, but not yet released. See [Wubi fails to detect 12.04.2 and 13.04 AMD64 ISO](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1134770)

Answer (score 0):

Now I installed 32 bit. Installation time is very fast. No need to extra download. I downloaded 32 bit iso and extract it. Then run the wubi.exe installer and follow the instructions. To complete the whole installation time is around 30 mins only.

I think 64 bits edition is something wrong with Wubi.exe !